# Selenium ActionChains moves cursor to the dropdown object and clicks behind it

Tags: python, selenium

The following code (Python):

**1.** moves cursor to a dropdown object, 

**2.** that move closes dropdown window, 

**3.** cursor clicks on a place where dropdown object initially was. 
How can I make it to hover over a dropdown and click on the necessary option?
Thank you

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains


    def test_one():
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="path")
        driver.get("https://www.imdb.com/")
        driver.maximize_window()
        action = ActionChains(driver)
        action.move_to_element(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("label[class*='navbar'] div")).click().perform()
        search_options = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[class*='ipc-list__item _1x']")
        for option in search_options:
            if option.text == "Celebs":
                action.move_to_element(option).click().perform()
```

Comment: What's the objective? Please try to be as clear as possible, eg: I need to click  at `X` or `Y`. Do you need to make a `celeb` search? is that it?

Comment: Yes, I need open IMDB website, then I need to click on the button to the left of the search field (It says "All" on it). After that I need to click on "Celebs" option from a dropdown menu. Thank you

Comment: What's your goal with this? what are you trying to do?

Comment: Just automatic practice